# NameError: name 'split' is not defined

Tags: python

I am running the python script as follows,the second arugment is a comma(",") seperated input..am trying to split this arugment based on "," and keep appending the 
output of each filter_log  for each string to output.txt
1.)am getting the below error while doing so?
2.)how to keep appending to output.txt  for each search string passed in second argument?

ERROR:-

```
string = split(",",sys.argv[2])
NameError: name 'split' is not defined
```

USAGE:-

```
python test.py input.log loc\modem,loc\data
```

CODE:-

```
import sys
import string

def filter_log(input_file, output_file, strs):
    with open(input_file, "r") as input, open(output_file, "w") as output:
        output.writelines(filter(lambda x: all([s in x for s in strs]), input.readlines()))

# here is just searched for "Warning", add other stuff
#filter_log("input.txt", "output.txt", ["Warning"])

print sys.argv[1]
print sys.argv[2]
for arg in sys.argv[2]:
    string = split(",",sys.argv[2])
    filter_log(sys.argv[1], "output.txt", ["Warning",string])
```

Answer (score 11):

You have a syntax error (**EDIT:** Not a syntax error, but simply a mistake). You meant:

`string = sys.argv[2].split(",")`

Comment: Also, it's a bad practice to use names like `string` as variable names.  In this case, you had previously (unnecessarily) imported the `string` module; declaring `string = sys.argv[2].split(",")` means you no longer have a name available to refer to that module.

Comment: I'll end the suspense -- this is a mistake but not a syntax error, since in Python using a name that hasn't been defined isn't a syntax error, it's a perfectly well-defined code snippet in the language. It's just that it's defined to throw an exception, which isn't what the questioner wants to do.

Comment: So you were telling the user he has a `NameError`? I think he already knew that, given that's the title of the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. `import` does **not** work like C's `include`. It creates a *module object* with the name of the module which you can use to reference attributes, i.e. use `string.split(sys.argv[2], ',')` and not `split(sys.argv[2], ',')`
2. Almost all the functions in the `string` module are deprecated. Strings have methods, use them! `sys.argv[2].split(',')`
3. `string = split(",",sys.argv[2])` do you realize that after this assignment is executed you will *not* be able to reference the `string` module anymore? *Never* use the name of built-in function/types/modules as names of variables!